# Referencial integrity in MongoDB. Which is a better practice?

Tags: mongodb, join, nosql

Let's say I have a Document and an author collections. I could design it in two ways:

1st way:

```
documents
{_id:1, title:"document 1", author:"John", age: 34}
{_id:2, title: "document 2", author: "Maria", age:42 }
{_id:3, title: "document 3", author: "John", age: 34}

authors
{_id:1, name:"John", age:34}
{_id:2, name:"Maria", age:42}
```

2nd way:

```
documents
{_id:1, title:"document 1", id_author:1}
{_id:2, title: "document 2", id_author: 2}
{_id:3, title: "document 3", id_author: 1}

authors
{_id:1, name:"John", age:34}
{_id:2, name:"Maria", age:42}
```

1st way is good because I don't have to simulate a Join when I retrieve a document, I have all the data in the documents collection. But, on the other hand, if I have to change Maria's age, I have to do it in both collections.

2nd way is the opposite, if I need a document and the age of it's author I need to query documents first and then authors. But the good thing is that when I have to change Maria's age I only have to do it in the authors collection.

So, which solution is better? I guess that the more fields you need in authors collection the more likely you'll be using the second way. But, if I am using the 1st way, is there a single query I can use to update the age of Maria in both collections?

Which is the most used solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update in more than one collection would be a transaction. MongoDB does not support transactions.

Both ways have their own disadvantages.

The first way which is author-data inclusive may be more appropriate in logging situations where its contents won't be subject to change.

The second way is better when you expect the author's details to change or grow over time (most cases).

Like already mentioned, embedding the documents in their respective author's document would be a way to combine the 2 suggestions' benefits but may lead to problems in the long run.

Comment: An update which occurs more than one collection does not have to be transactional, that is just a feature of the ACID paradigm. You can also have a transactional update for a single table in ACID compliant programs

Comment: @Sammaye Of course transactions can happen on a single table as well. I can't recall seeing an update between two tables that was not transactional. Might look into it out of curiosity, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the first method is updates:

```
{_id:1, title:"document 1", author:"John", age: 34}
```

I can imagine that actually you will want an author id in there as well as some of the details you need for querying (schema redundancy).

This could pose a problem, as you notice:

> But, on the other hand, if I have to change Maria's age, I have to do it in both collections.

Age changes once every year at least, and if you have the age wrong, more often. Name can change as well, especially if later on you find that this "John" has a last name or his name is actually "Johnny".

So the problem with creating redundancy here is that the author document could change dramatically causing you to have to run extremely unperformant updates which could massively increase your working set at times. As to how often it would cause this I cannot say with the information provided, that will be upto you decide.

Normally a good way to create redundancy is when you need extremely rarely updated attributes in another document in your current document. This does not seem to be the case here.

The second way is normally the default way of doing this kind of randomly read and updated relationship however there is a possible third method - embedding.

You could embed the documents into the author. This depends on how many documents you are looking to store though since MongoDB has a max document size of 16Meg.

That being said a possibility is:

```
{
    _id: {},
    name: 'John',
    age: 43,
    documents: [
        { id: 1, title: "New Document" }
    ]
}
```

The one down side of this is the use of in-memory operations such as `$pull` or `$push` and not only that but if your document is consistently and vastly growing you could see fragmentation.

But again these are just notes for you to take in, the realiy depends upon information not provided.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a mix of both approaches, the "static" information will be saved along with the documents collection, and the variable data will be centralized in the authors collection, only when the variable data requires to be retrieved I will use the author id to retrieve his age. Something like this:

```
documents
{_id:"1", title:"document 1", author:"John", authorId: "1"}
{_id:"2", title: "document 2", author: "Maria", authorId: "2"}
{_id:"3", title: "document 3", author: "John", authorId: "1"}

authors
{_id:"1", name:"John", age:34}
{_id:"2", name:"Maria", age:42}
```

Age is something you wouldn't required too often, but could be updated frequently therefore this will handle better both situations.

As someone else mentioned, Mongo is not transactional and you could have problems if you create the author and the document in one shot.

Comment: The authorId field should not contain a string "1" but the number 1 though.

Comment: Actually most of the nosql solutions (including Djondb, the db I represent) use guids as identifiers, that's why I would leave it as chars, but yes the type actually is not a big deal in NoSQL solutions, (fixed the ints are now chars, just a copy'n paste error)